# Calculate div overlap area and position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have two divs absolutely positioned, is it possible to calculate where these two divs overlap and then draw another div to place on top of the overlapping area.

I have been searching around the web and most things I have come to is only concerned with overlap detection, [like this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98sAG/)

I don't understand how to get the following positions for the overlap area:

```
offsetTop
offsetLeft
width
height
```

Any help would be appreciated in pointing me where I would start with this.

I have [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GApu5/) for what I have been playing with - you will see that I am trying to create a div to sit on the overlapping part and colour it a mixture of the two colours

Comment: In essence this seems to be a duplicate of [how-to-find-rectangle-intersection-on-a-coordinate-plane](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7356/how-to-find-rectangle-intersection-on-a-coordinate-plane)

Comment: @zsawyer That doesn't really tell me how to get the coordinates with javascript though and I'm not sure how you would apply the mathematical formula of the best answer

Comment: does this means anything to you? http://api.jquery.com/category/css/

Comment: @steo, I know how to use jQuery, just not how to calculate the intersection points

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't error checked it yet, but I believe you wanting something like: http://jsfiddle.net/GApu5/4/

with the calculations as follows:

```
var l1=div1.offset().left-8;
var t1=div1.offset().top-8;
var w1=div1.width();
var h1=div1.height();

var l2=div2.offset().left-8;
var t2=div2.offset().top-8;
var w2=div2.width();
var h2=div2.height();    

var top = Math.max(t1,t2);
var left = (l2>l1 && l2<(l1+w1)) ? l2 : (l1>l2 && l1<(l2+w2)) ? l1 : 0;
var width = Math.max(Math.min(l1+w1,l2+w2) - Math.max(l1,l2),0);
var height = Math.max(Math.min(t1+h1,t2+h2) - Math.max(t1,t2),0);
overlay.css({'top': top, 'left': left, 'width': width, 'height': height});
```

and to show works all sides: http://jsfiddle.net/GApu5/5/

Comment: what are the `-8` for?  I copied his code into my fiddle and I had to change the top to `-10`

Comment: ah it was being pushed out by the margin and on the wrapper and body.  Thanks this is perfect

Comment: yeah, I didn't check, but margins, padding, borders etc will affect it slightly